# BigQuery timestamp field in Data Studio error

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have data in a BigQuery instance with a some date fields in epoch/timestamp format. I'm trying to convert to a YYYYMMDD format or similar in order to create a report in Data Studio. I have tried the following solutions so far:

- Change the format in the Edit Connection menu when creating the Data Source in Data Studio to Date format. Not working. I get Configuration errors when I add the field to the Data Studio report.
- Create a new field using the TODATE() function. I always get an invalid formula error (even when I follow the documentation for this function). I have tried to change the field type prior to use the TODATE() function. Not working in any case.

Am I doing something wrong? Why do I always get errors?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using Data Studio for the conversion, can you use `PARSE_DATE` or `PARSE_TIMESTAMP` in BigQuery and convert it there instead?

Answer (score 1):

The function for `TODATE()` is actually `CURRENT_DATE()`. Change timestamp to DATE using `EXTRACT(DATE from variableName)`
make sure not use Legacy SQL !
The issue stayed, but changing the name of the variable from `actual_delivery_date` to `ADelDate` made it work. So I presume there's a bug and short(er) names may help to avoid it

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Elliott Brossard, the solution would be instead of using Data Studio for the conversion,use `PARSE_DATE` or `PARSE_TIMESTAMP` in BigQuery and convert it there instead.